# display images in gridview from imagepath stored in database in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

Scenario: In database we have a column of varchar type that contains the path of images to be displayed and in dotnet application we have a gridview which has columns varchar type. Now in this column we need to display the images which are in application project images folder.

we are using below method but getting System.drawing.bitmap written in gridviewimagecolumn

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row1 in dgvDisplayTiles.Rows)
{
    string imgPath;
    imgPath= (Application.StartupPath + row1.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
    Image imageFile = Image.FromFile(imgPath);
    if (imgPath != null)
    {
        //img.Image=imgPath;
        row1.Cells[3].Value = imageFile;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Path");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the type of your cells[3] cell?

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer: varchar type

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you combine wrong path.

you should use:

```
imgPath= Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, row1.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
```

instead of:

```
imgPath= (Application.StartupPath + row1.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
```

full code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row1 in dgvDisplayTiles.Rows)
{
    string imgPath;
    imgPath= Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, row1.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
    Image imageFile = Image.FromFile(imgPath);
    if (imgPath != null)
    {
        //img.Image=imgPath;
        row1.Cells[3].Value = imageFile;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Path");
    }
}
```

**Update#2 :**

You can create dynamic columns like this:

For the easy understanding, i create an Employee class and add some dummy data and bind it with the DataGridView

```
public class Employee
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string imagePath { get; set; }
}


private void bindGrid()
{
    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
    employees.Add(new Employee() {  id = "1",name = "joseph", imagePath = "abc.png" });
    employees.Add(new Employee() {  id = "2", name = "Mac", imagePath = "capture2.png" });
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = employees;

    DataGridViewImageColumn column = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    column.Name = "imgColumn1";
    column.HeaderText = "Image";
    this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
    this.dataGridView1.Refresh();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row1 in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        string imgPath;
        imgPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, row1.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
        Image imageFile = Image.FromFile(imgPath);

        if (imgPath != null)
        {
            row1.Cells[3].Value = imageFile;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Path");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it displays same "System.drawing.bitmap" in gridview

Comment: what is stored in your row1.Cells[3].Value.ToString() ?

Comment: we are assigning image path here. In database all the imagepaths are stored.

Comment: in my opinion you can add another column of `Image` type and set the value of that cell to **imageFile**, because currently your `row1.Cells[3]` is of string(varchar) column, while to display image you should have a `ImageType` column.

Comment: requirement was to create the gridview dynamically and fetch the whole database table details into that gridview and we need to display image by reading path in last column i.e. cells[3]. Also can we define column type dynamically in gridview, if yes how to set it of imagetype?

Comment: Now I have set the column imagetype, still it is not showing image however we are able to fetch the path of image.

Comment: i have update the code for creating dynamic column. I hope it will help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: You can do one thing, just add a hidden column and a image column and bind your image path in hidden column. Then in your foreach iteration,  get the path from the hidden column and show it in the actual image column.

Comment: How this will work when I have 6 images column and 3 text columns in one row?